# Equivalent method in Java for np.random.uniform()

Tags: java, python, random, distribution, uniform-distribution

I'm trying port a python code into java and am stuck at one place. Is there any method in java that is equivalent to numpy.random.uniform() in python?

Comment: Java Random is uniformly distributed as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean(). numpy.random.uniform gives some additional syntax support which can possibly be encapsulated via a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can't do that in java, at least without a library, but you can try something like this.

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Double> numbers = DoubleStream.generate(() -> random.nextFloat() * range).limit(100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That will generate a list of 100 float numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

- Random rnd = new Random();
- rnd.nextInt(int boundary);
- rnd.nextDouble(double boundary);
- rnd.next();

If you want a list of randoms the best way is probably ti write your own little method, just use an array and fill it with a for loop.